# Java set focus on JButton when pressing enter

Tags: java, swing

How can I make it so that when I press enter in a JTextField it activates a specific JButton? What I mean is something along the lines of a web page form where you can press enter to activate the button in the form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use an `Action` for the `JButton`:

```
Action sendAction = new AbstractAction("Send") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // do something
    }
};

JButton  button = new JButton(sendAction);
```

Then you can set the same action for a `JTextField` or even on a `MenuItem` if you want the same action to be available in the Menu:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setAction(sendAction);
```

Comment: +1, cool, I didn't even know about the setAction() method. I've always used addActionListener. Either way this is the better solution.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work:

```
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        button.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried that and it puts the focus on the button, but it doesn't activate it.

Comment: It won't, the requestFocusInWindow() method does what it says on the tin. To simulate a click the doClick() method is what you're after.

Comment: @LOD121, this is not the proper solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by adding the `default` behavior to the button, like this

```
cmdLogin.setDefaultCapable(true); // by default, this is true
this.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(cmdLogin); // here `this` is your parent container
```

Comment: +1, but beware: that'll work only as long as the textField does _not_ have a Action attached.

Comment: yup. that is true. but in this case, this should work and i hope the aim of post author was to get the `default` behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like the following:

```
textField.addKeyListener(
  new KeyAdapter() {
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
       if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
          button.doClick();
       }
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: @LOD121, Yes it works, but this is not the way the text field was designed to be used.

Comment: I have to agree and admit I too was unaware of the setAction() method! We learn something every day eh?

Comment: -1 for keyListener - even without being aware of the Action api, it should be a keyBinding ;-)